# Unable to Zoom d3 techanjs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, techan.js

I'm using almost same code which has been used in http://techanjs.org/. I was trying to add zooming feature in the chart as the developer has rendered the chart in [here](http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/edf630690c10b89be390). But somehow I'm not able to zoom it. I'm getting error selection is not defined in console. I'm using following code to render the chart. https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/7gJq9wKL4h4s862EDuxnQQ. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in here, I would really appreciate if I get any assistance regarding it as I'm still learning D3.

Comment: Really hard to say without a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example 
 - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - for example what is throwing the error, which call? Without more information it is pretty hard to help.

Comment: It's really difficult to minimize it because I really want the other features along with the zoom and not sure if I try to minify it will produce the same error or not.

Comment: Then it is a vote to close once the bounty clears - Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. The simple error is because you are trying to use "selection" in functions where it isn't defined.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess the problem is that you are referencing the variable `selection` but it isn't defined.

Hence -

> selection is not defined

`selection` is the parameter passed into your `bigchart` function.

But you then use it in your `reset`, `zoomed` functions where it is not defined.

```
//Zoom Begins
 function reset() {
        zoom.scale(1);
        zoom.translate([0,0]);
        selection.call(draw); // this will throw an error
    }

    function zoomed() {
        x.zoomable().domain(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(zoomableInit).domain());
        y.domain(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yInit).domain());
        yPercent.domain(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yPercentInit).domain());

        selection.call(draw); // this will throw an error
    }
//Zoom Ends
```

To fix, either pass the selection to the functions as a parameter (like the other functions) - or else make the `selection` a property of `BigChart` so that it can be referenced by the `reset` and `zoomed`functions.

i.e.

```
 // pass selection to the functions as a parameter

 function reset(selection) {
    zoom.scale(1);
    zoom.translate([0,0]);
    selection.call(draw);
 }

 function zoomed(selection) {
    x.zoomable().domain(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(zoomableInit).domain());
    y.domain(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yInit).domain());
    yPercent.domain(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yPercentInit).domain());
    selection.call(draw);
 }
```

Then when you call the functions obviously you pass in the correct object...e.g.

```
zoom = selection.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed));
```

rather than

```
zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed),
```

Comment: I just tried the code, if I use zoom = selection.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed)); I'm getting selection is not defined on that very line and the chart is not rendering. However, if I use zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed), chart is rendering fine but I'm getting the error while trying to zoom. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - the example zoom = selection.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed)); was to show how you might pass the selection - it wasn't for you to copy and paste. Obviously "selection" is undefined before you use it - that is the root of your problem!

Comment: I found another set of codes in http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/edf630690c10b89be390 is it possible to resize it as per browser width? Because in here the zoom works perfectly fine.